# Difference between Activiti and BPM Symbols

Tags: jbpm, activiti

I am newbie in Activiti.
I'm researching about Activiti and Bpmn. 
I have a question: are there any difference between Activiti and Bpmn symbols? (Example: There are some symbols in Activiti but don't have in Bpmn )
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're noticing the custom extensions that are not part of the bpmn2 specification - these are the xml elements or attributes that begin with `activiti:`. There's a [section in the user guide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnConstructs) which explains that these can provide functions not directly catered for by the specification or can sometimes be shorthands. Some of these can be [activiti-specific task types](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCamelTask) so you'll see symbols for these in activiti graphical design tools.